# PHP Laravel Foreach trough multi array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I have the following multi dimension array and I am not able to do a foreach loop (with laravel). I want to show the name.
Any idea how to loop trough that array to show just the name? I reduced the showed array -> ...

I want to loop trough that array not in a view but in a controller because i want to create a database entry for every client

```
array:1 [▼
  "client" => array:52 [▼
    0 => array:11 [▼
      "name" => "Company One"
     ...
    ]
    1 => array:11 [▼
      "name" => "Company 2"
     ...
    ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can we take a look of what you have done so far?

Comment: share the code where you print it and how to send it to view ?

Comment: Can we see your `.blade.php` view where you `@foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

Its easy all you have to do is this ,lets assume that your array are in the varibale $myArray

```
    $myArray = [▼
  "client" => array:52 [▼
    0 => array:11 [▼
      "name" => "Company One"
     ...
    ]
    1 => array:11 [▼
      "name" => "Company 2"
     ...
    ]
```

then you have to do:

```
    @foreach ($myArray->client as $data)

         {{$data->name}}

   @endforeach
```

Comment: both parent and childs are arrays, not objects ;). Using object operator `->` to access them wont work

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [
    'client' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Company One',
            'foo' => 'Foo One',
        ],[
            'name' => 'Company 2',
            'foo' => 'Foo 2',
        ]
    ]
];

$names = array_pluck($array['client'], 'name');

foreach($names as $name) {
    echo $name; // Replace this with the logic to create DB entry
}
```